# Где взять знания?

Tags: c#

Профи, как действовать ?

Нравится очень C#. Делаю всякие софты для себя и знаю только небольшой кусочек базы.

- Типы переменных
- Массивы
- Логические / Циклические конструкции

Не понимаю ООП - максимум, делаю публичные классы чтобы просто не копился код в Form1 xD

Делал:

- Cкриншотер под себя
- Переводчик чата в играх, чтобы если на EN кто то написал, сразу перевод бы было видно.
- Кучу парсеров для сайтов
- И другие всякие мелочи

Но хочется хорошенько углубиться, так как устал спотыкаться в непонимание библиотек и приходится много времени тратить на то, чтобы понять какие классы есть и что с чем и как работает.

Посмотрел какие есть курсы:

- одни от вроде как связанны учителями от Microsoft поделены на кучу подкурсов по 40 часов 1 день в неделю.
- другие 140 часов какие то частники.

И ничего не понятно, всё плохо описано, нет отзывов и т.д. и нужны ли они вообще.. Так как готов поглощать информацию больше чем 1 раз в неделю.

Может быть какие то книги сесть читать или какие то конкретные курсы выбрать ? Можете подсказать что то ?

Хочу научиться проектировать софт, выбирать правильные библиотеки, ну и конечно же, писать этот софт.

Спасибо!

Вот как сделали бы вы, пройдя уже через многое.

Comment: Найдите работу программистом, найдите на работе себе наставника, учите теорию и много практикуйтесь.

Comment: @tym32167 найти работу, не зная как её делать) ? То не как источник дохода, а как хобби, просто не знаю как правильно и эффективно начать поглощать инфу.

Comment: Правильно и эффективно - только изучение теории с применением знаний на практике. Но я не советую учить программирование ради программирования. Берите себе реальные задачи, которые делают что то полезное, и спрограмируйте их

Comment: @tym32167 вот примерно так и идёт), но начинаю спотыкаться в понимание библиотек.

Comment: Это нормально что то не понимать. Так и идет обучение - находишь что то, чего не понимаешь. Учишь это, начинаешь понимать, применяешь на практике.

Answer (score 2):

Есть хороший сайт udemy.com, можете найти интересующие вас курсы - это из платных, быстрых, не дорогих вариантов

А так вообще да, работа и практика будет принесут самый лучший опыт

Answer (score 1):

Если не хочешь идти на работу программистом, попробуй присоединиться к какому-нибудь опенсорсному проекту. И пусть твой код кто-то более опытный ревьювит.

Это даст хороший буст в скилах т.к. ты получишь опыт работы с реальным проэктом, опыт коммуникации и взаимодействия с другими программистами в рамках одного проекта, опыт соответствия некоему чужому кодстайлу и получишь наставления от более опытного человека.

Answer (score -1):

Сколько людей столько и мнений. На этот вопрос нельзя дать однозначный ответ, и поэтому его лучше закрыть. Шуточный план по которому мне рекомендовал учиться преподаватель ВУЗа:

```
 1. поймите ООП и основы ЯП, получите диплом (я тоже на этом этапе)
 2. идите дальше, изучая патерны программирования;
 3. Изучите web-разработку с использованием Вашего ЯП, фреймворки
 4. Выполнять заказы на фриланс-бирже (или пойти на работу в офис);
 5. Заработанные 100500 тысяч иностранной валюты потратьте на личный остров
```

А если серьезно, то вот [список книг по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c) Все остальное уже личное мнение и не претендует на истинность

Answer (score -1):

Главное практика, поставьте задачу или ряд задач по типу от легкого к сложному. И начните ее реализовывать с помощью классов в стиле ООП. Мне тоже предстоит изучать классы в C# думаю, немного почитав о классах, начинаю примерно понимать какие задачи буду реализовывать на практике.